# Hox to fix "package R does not exist setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)"

Tags: java, gradle, apk, android-virtual-device

I'm running `./gradle assembleDebug` and i'm having this error

```
...app/src/main/java/com/name/app/MainActivity.java:11: error: package R does not exist
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

if i run it with --info:

```
Caching disabled for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Watching 47 directories to track changes
Watching 46 directories to track changes
Watching 45 directories to track changes
Full recompilation is required because no incremental change information is available. This is usually caused by clean builds or changing compiler arguments.
Compiling with toolchain '/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64'.
```

I had previously ran `gradle clean`, but I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

I tried changing things in my .xml files, but it keeps failing, I have no idea how to fix it.
This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:label="app"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.name.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should add import for R class: `import com.name.app.R;`

Comment: @marcinj i did and now the error says `cannot find symbol import com.name.app.R`